# Same code works in main, but not when calling from a function in C

Tags: c, function, function-call

Okay so I'm a beginner programmer so any tips on any part of the code are greatly appreciated,
but the main question is why does the code in function `int longestSequence(int n,int array[n]);`work when placed in main, but not when called from the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int longestSequence(int n,int array[n]);

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int mat[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    int arraySize = n*n;
    int array[arraySize];
    int arrayIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
                array[arrayIndex++] = mat[i][j];
            }
        }else{
            for(int j = n-1; j>=0; j--){
                array[arrayIndex++] = mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

/// Here's the same code that works when in main
//    int numOfSequental = 0;
//    int maxNumOfSequental = INT_MIN;
//        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
//        if(niz[i] == (niz[i+1]-1)){
//            numOfSequental++;
//            if(numOfSequental>maxNumOfSequental){
//                maxNumOfSequental = numOfSequental;
//            }
//            continue;
//        }
//        numOfSequental = 0;
//    }

//calling the function in printf
    printf("Length of the sequence: %d", longestSequence(arraySize, array[arraySize]));
    return 0;
}

int longestSequence(int n,int array[n])
{
    int numOfSequental = 0;
    int maxNumOfSequental = INT_MIN;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if(array[i] == (array[i+1]-1)){
            numOfSequental++;
            if(numOfSequental>maxNumOfSequental){
                maxNumOfSequental = numOfSequental;
            }
            continue;
        }
        numOfSequental = 0;
    }
    return maxNumOfSequental+1;
}
```

Comment: How specifically does it (not) function? Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it give the wrong result? What result does it give, and what result did you expect instead? Can you post a minimal _non-interactive_ example with a hardcoded matrix instead of prompting for input, so people can reproduce the problem without guessing what values they should enter?

Comment: **Undefined Behaviour**: accessing `array[i+1]` when `i` is `n-1` (last time through the loop) is out of bounds.

Comment: Call the function as `longestSequence(arraySize, array)` -- you want to pass the "whole array", not one element of it. I'm sure we have plenty duplicate answers for passing arrays into functions in C, but can't find a good one at the moment.

Comment: `int main()` was fashionable (?) and reasonable (?!) in the mid 80's.  For modern code, you should use `int main(void)` or (preferrably) `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: Don't use scanf to read parameters; that's what the 2nd argument of `main` is for.  If you're going to use `scanf`, *always* check its return value.  `if( scanf("%d", &n) == 1 ){ ... }`.

Comment: @pmg oh, thank you, wouldn't have noticed that!

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm currently a first year computer engineering student, so I am working off what they teach us (some of which is probably old fashioned or maybe just dumbed down for us beginners), thank you for the feedback will look into it.

Comment: @Useless sorry!! This is my first time posting here, will do that next time since this is solved.

Comment: @WilliamPursell all published versions of the C standard and the current (Jan 2022) draft standard show  `int main()` in several examples. Apparently the standard committee see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It is (unfortunately) true that it appears in examples, but 5.1.2.2.1 (https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1) is very explicit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it says "or equivalent", which is not that explicit. Is `int main(){}` equivalent to `int main(void){}`? If not, why not? Or perhaps, why *still* not? There is no reason not to treat these as equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"the main question is why does the code in function `int longestSequence(int n,int array[n]);` work when placed in main, but not
> when called from the function?"*

As called it should not work in either place.

```
printf("Length of the sequence: %d", longestSequence(arraySize, array[arraySize]));
//                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
return 0;
```

Note first that the index passed: `arraySize` is one beyond the legal index for `array`.  In C, indexing is zero based, and so it goes from `0` - `arraySize - 1`
More importantly though the 2nd argument of `longestSequence` should be a pointer to the array, not an indexed element of the array.

```
printf("Length of the sequence: %d", longestSequence(arraySize, array));
return 0;
```

Also, in general, to compare subsequent numbers in an array with size `n`, the range of comparisons should be limited to:

```
a[i] == a[i+1] //for i == 0 through i == n-1
```

Change:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    //          ^^^
    if(array[i] == (array[i+1]-1)){//array out of bounds when i == n
    //                    ^^^
```

To

```
 for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++){
    //          ^^^^^  
    if(array[i] == (array[i+1]-1)){//i will never reach n
```

*EDIT:*
One last thing addresses comment about replacing calls to `scanf()` with using the 2nd argument of main.  First to do that the code must include the prototype of main:   `int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`.  With this prototype, the program as called from the command line can now include command line arguments, eg: if running from CMD prompt in Windows:

```
C:\dev> myProg.exe 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Inside your program then arguments of `argc` and argv[]` are populated as follows:

```
argc == 11 //total number of arguments
argv[0] == "myProg.exe" //program name is alway in argv[0]
argv[1] == "3"
argv[2] == "1"
...
argv[10] == "9"
```

Which should translate to creating a 3x3 array populated with the 9 subsequent values.

So the first statements in your code could now be: (in psuedo code)

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);//check value of n before using
int array[n][n];
int index = 2;
for(int i = 0; i<n ; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<n ; j++)
        array[i][j] = atoi(argv[index]);
        index++;
```